# Calculate Time to Open for emails sent from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a query to calculate TimeToOpen for emails and I'm getting both positive and negative values. How can a time that the email was opened minus the time that the email was sent be negative ?

```
SELECT
a.SubscriberKey, 
DATEDIFF(minute, max(c.schedTime), max(b.EventDate)) as TimeToOpen 
FROM myDE a 
    left join _open b on a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
    join _job c on b.jobid = c.jobid 
                     
GROUP BY a.SubscriberKey
```

Thanks!
EDIT:
This works using _send

```
select 
a.SubscriberKey, 
DATEDIFF(second, max(c.EventDate), max(b.EventDate)) as TimeToOpen 
FROM IPW_Base_V2 a 
    left join _open b on a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
    join _sent c on b.SubscriberKey= c.SubscriberKey AND
                    b.JobID = c.JobID AND 
                    b.ListID = c.ListID AND 
                    b.BatchID = c.BatchID AND 
                    b.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID
                     
GROUP BY a.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Job data view instead of Sent data view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have negative results is that you are comparing Open's EventDate to Job's SchedTime. The job was updated on the data view for some reason and was scheduled for a later datetime.

If you query Job data view to get more information about the jobid that's returning negative value, you'll see that the job's CreatedDate is before the open's Eventdate.

**The solution?**

You need to join the Open data view to the Sent data view on the EventDate.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to understand why and in what situations the scheduled time can be after the open time and how to fix the query with _job. I think it could be the journey job when there is a wait time and a future job. 
Anyway, I mark your answer as correct as using _send works.

Comment: I added the working query to the question